# LIKE group_concat with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

i am using Like in group concat & i want to get all modules attached to client even if it does not match to LIKE,  i know that that i can do that with HAVING but i don't want to use HAVING, any solution with WHERE or in join condition ?

Any suggestions on how to get my expected result??

These are some basic tables and the query i tried along with results i get and the result i really wanted

Tables

```
Client
+--------------------+
| id      |  name    |
+--------------------+
| 1       | client1  |
| 2       | client2  |
| 3       | client3  |
| 4       | client4  |
+--------------------+

Module
+--------------------+
| id      |  name    |
+--------------------+
| 1       | module1  |
| 2       | module2  |
| 3       | module3  |
| 4       | module4  |
+--------------------+

Client_Module
+-------------------------+
| client_id  | module_id  |
+-------------------------+
| 1          | 1          |
| 1          | 3          |
| 2          | 1          |
| 2          | 2          |
| 2          | 4          |
| 3          | 2          |
| 4          | 1          |
| 4          | 2          |
| 4          | 3          |
| 4          | 4          |
+-------------------------+
```

Query:

```
SELECT     client.id, client.name, GROUP_CONCAT(module.name) AS modules
FROM       client
LEFT JOIN  client_module ON client_module.client_id = client.id
LEFT JOIN  module ON module.id = client_module.module.id
WHERE      module.name LIKE '%module1%'
group by client.id
```

Results:

```
Received
+--------------------------------------------------+
| id     | name     | modules                      |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| 1      | client1  | module1                      |
| 2      | client2  | module1                      |
| 4      | client4  | module1                      |
+--------------------------------------------------+

Expected
+------------------------------------------------------+
| id     | name     | modules                          |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 1      | client1  | module1,module3                  |
| 2      | client2  | module1,module2,module4          |
| 4      | client4  | module1,module2,module3,module4  |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why do you use `WHERE module.name LIKE '%module1%'`?

Comment: Why does client 3 not appear -seems to have taken module 1

Comment: i want to show all clients contain module name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible without `HAVING` by using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT  c.id, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(m.name) AS modules
FROM    client AS c
        INNER JOIN client_module AS cm
            ON cm.client_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN module AS m
            ON m.id = cm.module_id
WHERE   EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    client_module AS cm2
                    INNER JOIN module AS m2
                        ON m2.id = cm2.module_id
            WHERE   m2.name LIKE '%module1%' 
            AND     cm2.client_id = c.id
        )
GROUP BY  c.id, c.name;
```

But this is less efficient, and more verbose so offers no advantage whatsoever. I expect your reasons for using `HAVING` are largely unfounded, and the approach I would personally take is with a conditional count in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT  c.id, c.name, GROUP_CONCAT(m.name) AS modules
FROM    client AS c
        INNER JOIN client_module AS cm
            ON cm.client_id = c.id
        INNER JOIN module AS m
            ON m.id = cm.module_id
GROUP BY  c.id, c.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN m.name LIKE '%module1%' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

**[Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fda4c799b6056b337e850c4d88ee80af)**

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
SELECT     client.id, client.name, GROUP_CONCAT(module.name) AS modules
FROM       client
LEFT JOIN  client_module ON client_module.client_id = client.id
LEFT JOIN  module ON module.id = client_module.module.id
GROUP BY   client.id
HAVING     modules LIKE '%module1%'
```

Comment: i know that that i can do that with HAVING but i don't want to use HAVING, any solution with WHERE or in join condition ?